# Save object createted with new() method in Odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

I try to create invoice.
So I create account.move object and add line there (like in _onchange_purchase_auto_complete ).
But for return i need Object ID not NEWID.
How to save this object created using new() method ?

PS: I try save() but this method don't exist in odoo models only in tests.

```
 # Create vendor bill
    vendor_bill = self.env['account.move'].with_context({'check_move_validity': False}).new(values)
    po_lines = purchase_orders.mapped('order_line')
    new_lines = self.env['account.move.line']
    for line in po_lines.filtered(lambda l: not l.display_type):
        new_line = new_lines.new(line._prepare_account_move_line(vendor_bill))
        new_line.account_id = new_line._get_computed_account()
        new_line._onchange_price_subtotal()
        new_lines += new_line
    new_lines._onchange_mark_recompute_taxes()
```

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are looking for is the `create()` method.

```
vendor_bill = self.env['account.move'].with_context({'check_move_validity': False}).create(values)
# ... etc ...
line_ids = self.env['account.move.line'].create(new_line_values)
```